# Is there a wildcard for "any number" in Windows search

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, windows-search

When you search for a file in Windows 10, how do you specify a **wildcard for any number**?

To give you an example:
I know that a file is called something like: `some-picture-100x100.jpg`.

I do not really know the resolution. It could also be `some-picture-360x360.jpg`, but it definitely has **3 numbers on the left side** of an **x** and another **3 numbers on the right side** of it. How do I search for that?

Edit: If you know **RegEx**, what I'm looking for is the **equivalent to [0-9]**. It seems not to exist, but if it does, please let me know.

Comment: AFAIK the only two wildcards are * and ? While not perfect you could search "* ???x???.jpg"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't believe there's a specific wildcard for a "number" rather than a character, but you can make use of the DOS-type wildcards `*` and `?`.

`*` would match 0 or more characters, while `?` would match a single character.

You can also use the `filename:` flag to indicate you only want to search filenames.

For example, you could try this in the Windows Explorer search box: `filename:*-???x???.jpg`

Comment: Thank you. I thought there might be something equivalent to [0-9] in RegEx. Since I want to delete a lot of files that match this pattern, I have to be careful then not to delete anything that has letters instead of numbers at these positions.